# Why does JAX-RS doesn't support the 423 error code out-of-the-box?

Tags: jax-rs, error-code

I was using JAX-RS 2.1 and I found the `Response` class enum is missing the `423` error code.

Can anybody explain to me why?

I searched on the internet but not found any relevant thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Response.Status`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html) documentation:

> Commonly used status codes defined by HTTP, see HTTP/1.1 documentation for the complete list. Additional status codes can be added by applications by creating an implementation of `Response.StatusType`.

The [`423`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.3) status code is defined as part of [WebDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) in the [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918), which is an **extension** of the HTTP protocol.

Once [`423`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.3) is [registered in IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml), it can be considered a standard status code, but it's not defined in any of the documents that currently define the HTTP/1.1 protocol:

- [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230): Message Syntax and Routing
- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231): Semantics and Content
- [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232): Conditional Requests
- [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233): Range Requests
- [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234): Caching
- [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235): Authentication

---

There's a number of ways to return [`423`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.3) though. The simplest one is:

```
return Response.status(423).build();
```

Alternatively, you could implement [`Response.StatusType`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.StatusType.html), as suggested in the [`Response.Status`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html) documentation:

```
public static class LockedStatusType implements Response.StatusType {

    @Override
    public int getStatusCode() {
        return 423;
    }

    @Override
    public String getReasonPhrase() {
        return "Locked";
    }

    @Override
    public Response.Status.Family getFamily() {
        return Response.Status.Family.CLIENT_ERROR;
    }
}
```

And then return it:

```
return Response.status(new LockedStatusType()).build();
```